# How can I check the address registered with US Citizenship and Immigration Services?

Tags: usa, immigration

(Asking on behalf of a friend; I will phrase this as though it were me.)

I have applied for I-765 (Application for Employment Authorization) among others, with the U.S. CIS.  However, I may have had a mixup with the address submitted on the form.  My attorney may have submitted a change of address procedure for me, but I cannot be sure and I am having difficulty reaching this attorney.

How can I check which address the CIS currently has on record?

Comment: If you create an account at https://egov.uscis.gov/casestatus/landing.do  you'd be able to make address updates, as well as check the status of the application.

Comment: @Dorothy Will that work for forms submitted before the account is created?

Comment: it seems that it would, since it asks for a receipt number. I would hope that his attorney has provided that sort of documentation. Do you know what the issue is with the attorney?

Comment: The attorney is working pro-bono and has little incentive.  The receipt number does work in that field on the website linked, but recommends filing out another form for change of address if needed.  However, the change of address form won't allow you to reference the I-765 form in its drop-down boxes, so we cannot use that.

Comment: Why not file a change of address form, to ensure that the current/correct address is in the system, even if it's already been done.? As I understand it, having an incorrect/old address can affect the application process, so better to be safe.

Comment: That would work @Dorothy except that the website, and thus the form, doesn't allow you to select change of address with a I-765 form being referenced.  I don't know if that is by design or an oversight. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43692/discussion-between-dorothy-and-blackvegetable).

Answer (score 1):

USCIS has an online tool, [myUSCIS](https://egov.uscis.gov/casestatus/landing.do), through which applicants can see the status of their case and its full history. Certain updates, such as address, can be made in the system, as having an incorrect or outdated address could affect the application process.

> Think of your myUSCIS account as your home page to view your case status and history for most of the applications and petitions you have filed with USCIS. Creating an account is free and allows you to easily save your receipt numbers and view your entire case history.
>
> **Related Tools**
>   [Change of Address](https://egov.uscis.gov/coa/displayCOAForm.do)
>   [Submit a Case Enquiry](https://egov.uscis.gov/e-Request/Intro.do)
>   [USCIS Processing Times Enquiry](https://egov.uscis.gov/cris/processTimesDisplayInit.do)
>   [USCIS Office Locations](https://egov.uscis.gov/crisgwi/go?action=offices)